# Hide "var" type preview in new IntelliJ 2020.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just updated to IntelliJ 2020.2 and while some things are good some thing are bad..

When using the Java `var` feature IntelliJ now shows the type of it right next to the variable name which is completely useless to me and the only reason one uses `var` at all, because the type is already obvious.

```java
var a = "hello world".split(" ");
```

Displays in IntelliJ 2020.2 as

```java
var a (: String[]) = "hello world".split(" ");
```

(the type in parentheses being a balloon which you can't right-click or highlight)

How can I disable this useless feature?

Comment: I think it's called "Type hints" in the settings.

Comment: @marstran Thank you, that wasn't exactly it but it helped me find the correct setting. I'm not used to messing with IntelliJ's settings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inlay Hints | Java | **Implicit types**: Show hints:

[image: Implicit types hints]

Comment: Accepted because of the image, thanks for further helping any future readers!

Answer (score 1):

I found it. CTRL+ALT+S then search for Inlay Hints and select Inlay Hints -> Java -> Implict types and turn it off.

Wish it was pre-disabled because now I will have to turn it off everywhere.